# Label going out of screen bounds in Android, Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

I am having problem in android, where I have a label had have custom fonts applied. On a button click I am actually changing the font, the text, the color and also the font size. If the text is large, it just goes out of the screen. I want to to stay in the bounds of the screen and auto adjust it. I dont mind it coming to the next line.

Here is my label code:

```
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
center : 0,
textAlign : "center",
wordWrap : true,
});
$.boostMePage.add(label);
```

I am also doing a bit of 2D matrix animation, where I rotate the label to a particular angle. For it to stay in the center i have added the following:

```
    var matrix = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
        matrix = matrix.rotate(angle);
        // matrix = matrix.scale(2, 2); // I tried scaling it, but then font was truing blurred. :(
        label.font = {
            fontSize : "55",
            fontFamily : elementFont // This is my custom font
        };
        matrix = matrix.translate(0, 0); // This I have applied so that the font stays in the center of the screen. I am not quite sure if this is correct.
        var a = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
            transform : matrix,
            duration : 300,
            autoreverse : false,
            repeat : 1
        });
        label.animate(a);
```

It is going out of the screen.

Here is the link for the screenshot :

[Screenshot](http://i60.tinypic.com/15rdt93.png)

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: you haven't given any width to your label.

Comment: you should use a smaller fontSize then. You can define a fontsize for each screen !